# How to ignore comma in the text when converting csv to arff?

Tags: csv, weka, arff

If there are some kinds of value like "Washington, DC" in a a csv file, there will be an error when it is converted to arff using weka tool. Is there any solution to ignore this comma?

Comment: Can you post the code you're running and the exact text of the error message?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to edit the CSV file, then try escaping the commas with a `\`.

i.e Do a global find-replace for `,` to `\,`.